# Error counter (batch)

Tags: batch-file, logging

I have assembled a batch script (from pieces found on stackoverflow, of course) that searches for "ERROR:" string in log file and writes down previous non-error line.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set numbers=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"ERROR:" %MainLog%') do (
    set /A before=%%a-1, after=%%a+1
    set "numbers=!numbers!!before!: !before!: "
)

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %MainLog%  ^|findstr  /B "%numbers%" ^| findstr /V /C:"ERROR:"') do echo %%b) > %outputFile%
```

the idea is that from this log file:

```
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 1
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 2
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 3
07:37:56 ERROR: Could not find P(reportsWizard_CloseX.png) S: 0.7 T:     72,-2 within 100 screen searches
07:47:08 ERROR: Could not find P(reusablePickObject_quick_search.png) S: 0.7 T: -10,0 within 100 screen searches
07:56:24 ERROR: Could not find P(reusablePickObject_ClickStatus.png) S: 0.7 T: -37,17 within 100 screen searches
08:05:54 ERROR: Could not find P(reusablePickObject_ClickStatus.png) S: 0.7 T: -37,17 within 100 screen searches
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 4
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 5
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 6
07:37:56 ERROR: Could not find P(reportsWizard_CloseX.png) S: 0.7 T: 72,-2 within 100 screen searches
07:47:08 ERROR: Could not find P(reusablePickObject_quick_search.png) S: 0.7 T: -10,0 within 100 screen searches
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 7
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 8
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 9
```

it extracts only lines:

```
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 3
07:19:44     Generating SOFTWARE report number 6
```

It might not be perfect but it works so far, and now i would like to improve it in order to count how many error logs are written under non-error logs like this:

```
07:19:44    Generating SOFTWARE report number 3 (4 ERRORS)
07:19:44    Generating SOFTWARE report number 6 (2 ERRORS)
```

And that's it... So basically, I just need to add that brackets with error count, and I have no idea how to do it and is it worth of effort or even possible to do it in batch.
Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: look every line, count consecutive error lines and print the line before the errors with the counter (explanations in the code):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "last="
REM for every line do:
for /f "delims=" %%i in (test.log) do (
  REM does it contain "ERROR:"?
  echo %%i|find "ERROR:" >nul && (
    REM yes, then increase counter:
    set /a count+=1
   ) || ( 
    REM no, then print last "non ERROR" line and the counter:
    if !count! gtr 0 echo !last! ^(!count! Errors^)
    REM reset the counter for the next ERROR block:
    set count=0
    REM save last line:
    set "last=%%i"
  ) 
)
```

By removing `if !count! gtr 0` you'll get *every* report with the number of errors

Comment: Great, works perfectly...

definitely worth crating account here!

Comment: @Redundant you can upvote any answer to mark it as helpful and/or accept an answer if it solves your problem, so the question gets removed from the unanswered-queue

Comment: well tried but I got:
 thanks for the feedback! Once you earn  total of 15 reputation, your votes will change publicly displayed post score